# Recursive variable expansion in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a need to expand ASA access-lists for reference after a migration.
The ASA is gone now and I want to expand the object-group references to validate we captured all expected access.
I have a working idea for an ACL line with 4 object-groups.
My rub is ACLs could have 0-4 object-group references and I need a loop to run through and handle each possible combination.
I can write a loop for each possible combination but I know there has to be a more elegant way.

I already have code to expand and store the object groups individually, but substituting them in-line is the challenge.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

```
@line = ('access-list','vlan_in','extended','permit','object-group','ob1','object-group','ob2','object-group','ob3','object-group','ob4');
# @line = ('access-list','vlan_in','extended','permit','object-group','ob1','object-group','ob2','object-group','ob3','eq','53');
# @line = ('access-list','vlan_in','extended','permit','object-group','ob1','host','30.0.0.30','object-group','ob2','eq','23');
# @line = ('access-list','vlan_in','extended','permit','tcp','host','40.0.0.10','object-group','ob1','eq 80');

$OG{'ob1'} = ['tcp','udp'];
$OG{'ob2'} = ['10.0.0.10', '10.0.0.20'];
$OG{'ob3'} = ['20.0.0.15', '20.0.0.25'];
$OG{'ob4'} = ['eq 22', 'eq 443'];

foreach $ins4 (@{$OG{ob4}}) {
  foreach $ins1 (@{$OG{ob1}}) {
    foreach $ins2 (@{$OG{ob2}}) {
      foreach $ins3(@{$OG{ob3}}) {
        $buffer = "";
        foreach $element (@line) {
          if($element =~ /object-group/) { next; }
          $buffer = $buffer . ' ' . $element;
        }
        $buffer =~ s/ob1/$ins1/;
        $buffer =~ s/ob2/$ins2/;
        $buffer =~ s/ob3/$ins3/;
        $buffer =~ s/ob4/$ins4/;
        print "$buffer\n";
      }
    }
  }
}

(Current Output)
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.15 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.25 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.15 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.25 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.15 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.25 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.15 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.25 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.15 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.25 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.15 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.25 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.15 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.25 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.15 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.25 eq 443
```

I can brute force this but was hoping for some inspiration rather than repeating code excessively. I can write separate loops for each scenario, but was hoping for some inspiration on a more elegant way.

```
(if 3 occurrences of ob#)
# @line = ('access-list','vlan_in','extended','permit','object-group','ob1','object-group','ob2','object-group','ob3','eq','53');

foreach $ins1 (@{$OG{ob1}}) {
  foreach $ins2 (@{$OG{ob2}}) {
    foreach $ins3(@{$OG{ob3}}) {
      $buffer = "";
      foreach $element (@line) {
        if($element =~ /object-group/) { next; }
        $buffer = $buffer . ' ' . $element;
      }
      $buffer =~ s/ob1/$ins1/;
      $buffer =~ s/ob2/$ins2/;
      $buffer =~ s/ob3/$ins3/;
      print "$buffer\n";
    }
  }
}

(if 2 occurrences of ob#)
# @line = ('access-list','vlan_in','extended','permit','object-group','ob1','host','30.0.0.30','object-group','ob2','eq','23');

foreach $ins1 (@{$OG{ob1}}) {
  foreach $ins2 (@{$OG{ob2}}) {
    $buffer = "";
    foreach $element (@line) {
      if($element =~ /object-group/) { next; }
      $buffer = $buffer . ' ' . $element;
    }
    $buffer =~ s/ob1/$ins1/;
    $buffer =~ s/ob2/$ins2/;
    print "$buffer\n";
  }
}

(if 1 occurrence of ob#)
# @line = ('access-list','vlan_in','extended','permit','tcp','host','40.0.0.10','object-group','ob1','eq 80');

foreach $ins1 (@{$OG{ob1}}) {
  $buffer = "";
  foreach $element (@line) {
    if($element =~ /object-group/) { next; }
    $buffer = $buffer . ' ' . $element;
  }
  $buffer =~ s/ob1/$ins1/;
  print "$buffer\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with the code or/and what other/more you want to do?  (But then, indeed, I don't know your "ASA"/"ACL"/"object-groups"/etc problem.)

Comment: The example I provided works currently. I was hoping to find another way for me to handle lines that could also have less than 4 replacements without writing a seperate foreach loop per scenario. (The other @line arrays I provided are examples)

Comment: OK. So your `@line` has `ob1` through `ob4`, or perhaps not all of them; if some are missing the regex `s///` for those just won't do anything to `$buffer`.  Is that what you mean by "_could also have less than 4 replacements_"?

Comment: The one problem I see is that `ob4` must come last -- and be there -- since its regex is the only one without a trailing space.  If that's the only issue then just make space optional  (or an alternation with the end of string anchor).

Comment: On my end, it works. (perl 5.26.0)

Comment: With these examples, yes; but if `@line` happens to end with `ob1` or `ob2` or `ob3` then it won't work (because there'll be no space behind them and the regex expects it).  But, maybe your data can't ever be that way, in which case it will work.  So then what you are asking here is simply for a nicer / cleaner / ... way to write this?

Comment: Correct, I was hoping to discover a different approach for this. ob4 was first on my list for ease of viewing the output, any order of ob[1-4] works. The order of ob1 to ob4 does not matter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a cross-product of the values in `%OG`.  [CPAN](https://metacpan.org) to the rescue.  The following code uses  [Set::Product](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Product) to create the cross-products.

```
use Set::Product qw[ product ];

my @line = (
    'access-list',  'vlan_in', 'extended',     'permit',
    'object-group', 'ob1',     'object-group', 'ob2',
    'object-group', 'ob3',     'object-group', 'ob4'
);

# same order as things fed to product
my @placeholders = qw[ ob1 ob2 ob3 ob4 ];

product {
    # for efficiency, this should be done outside of this loop
    my $buffer = join( ' ', grep { !/object-group/ } @line );

    # product places the values in @_; shift them off in order
    $buffer =~ s/$_/shift()/ge for @placeholders;

    print $buffer . "\n";
}
  [ 'tcp',         'udp' ],
  [ '10.0.0.10', '10.0.0.20' ],
  [ '20.0.0.15', '20.0.0.25' ],
  [ 'eq 22',     'eq 443' ]
;
```

which results in

```
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.15 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.15 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.25 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.25 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.15 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.15 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.25 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit tcp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.25 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.15 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.15 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.25 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.10 20.0.0.25 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.15 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.15 eq 443
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.25 eq 22
access-list vlan_in extended permit udp 10.0.0.20 20.0.0.25 eq 443
```

Comment: Almost forgot to circle back and thank you. This was EXACTLY what I was looking for.